# read a part of variable $this

Tags: php, arrays, magento, this

I try to debug a function in Magento, I have a very big and complexe variable $this, inside I find the data I need but I can't read that I search the data in the part named "html"

```
$html=$this->*Mage_Core_Block_Abstract*_transportObject['_data["html"]'];
```

the first problem the * in the name are not reconized.

Comment: I've never seen a property with asterisks in the name, but I suppose you can access them like this:          `$this->{'*Mage_Core_Block_Abstract*_transportObject'}`

Comment: In which class are you using $this? Probably you're doing something very wrong... `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract` is and abstract block class... probably you need something else and `_transportObject` is a private static property.
If you're extending `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract` you could use `self::$_transportObject->getHtml()`

Comment: Since it's private you shouldn't be able to access it... but if you take a look inside `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract` at `final public function toHtml()` it might be what you're looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my observers I use:

```
  $transport = $observer->getTransport();
  $html = $transport->getHtml();
```

This would lead me to believe that you could slightly modify those two lines as follows:

```
  $transport = $this->getTransport();
  var_dump($transport);
  $html = $transport->getHtml();
```

Then you should be able to read whatever you want.

Comment: If this doesnt work, wherever it might be that you are trying it, let me know and i will give you some quick code to create an observer to the core_block_abstract_to_html_after event which is where i always have success with this method.

Comment: Hi I try but I don't understand how create the observer, I work in app/desing/adminhtml//default/default/template/payment/info/pdf/default.phtml  I try to read $this->_transportObject  because in side in the html exist the name of pdf( order confirmation, invoice etc) well I try to make a condition to print payment instructions only in order confirmation

Comment: What you are attempting to do is not really supposed to be in a template file. Have you created a module for your functionality? If so, you set up the event in your module's config.xml and then you create the observer method in the class you declared in your config.xml for the observer.

Comment: yes I create all but I'm not sure what event I need catch to obtain the transportObject

Comment: core_block_abstract_to_html_after

Comment: Thanks to help and the conseils, finally don't works that but I find a solution  to my need, print payment instructions only in order confirmation,  in the module, I create a bypass and not use {{var payment}}